# Spring Cloud Feign not mapping to Eureka registered Application Name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I currently have two services that are being registered on a Eureka server called RESTAURANT and MENU.
[image: Eureka Server]

These names are defined in each service's boostrap.yml file as:

```
spring:
   application:
      name: menu
```

However, when it comes to using Netflix's Feign, I enter the application name in the annotation as follows:

```
@FeignClient("MENU")
public interface MenuClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/restaurants/{restaurantId}/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json")
    public Menu getMenu(@PathVariable("restaurantId") final Long restaurantId);
}
```

which eventually results in the URL not getting mapped to the eureka service, but rather to http://MENU.
[image: debugging snapshot]

I confirm that the feign client works if I hard code the url in the annotation, however this prevents me from generating random ports for my services.

What am I missing here? This feign client is in the RESTAURANT service.

### EDIT:

My main class for Restaurant Service

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class RestaurantApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestaurantApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your main spring boot application class please

Comment: @Arno_Geismar updated question

Comment: The url is correct. Replacement happens at runtime when the call is being made, since there could be multiple instances.

Comment: @spencergibb Are you suggesting that http://Menu will eventually be translated to http://localhost:3002? If that is the case, I still have something wrong with my setup because it never performs the call.

Comment: Indeed, that's how service discovery works. Can you provide a project that recreates the problem

Comment: I can provide the github link. https://github.com/PatrickBuhagiar/TimeToEat/blob/master/restaurant/src/main/java/com/soar/timetoeat/restaurant/dao/MenuClient.java This links points to the menu client in the question. To simulate the problem, you'd have to change the Feign parameters

Comment: It worked for me https://gist.github.com/spencergibb/08e35784dc9e5f3b34f2bb096de4ea94

Comment: Sorry for taking long to respond. I had set aside this problem and used direct urls instead for a while, but I've now I've understood why it was not working for me. The solution was to add `preferIpAddress: true` for each of my registered eureka services. Initially with hostnames, http calls with Feign were taking too long, which resulted in a Hystrix timeout. in switching to IpAddresses, this is no longer the case. As @spencergibb mentioned, this was correct all along, I just did not realise what the actual problem was.

Comment: By adding "eureka.instance.preferIpAddress:true" in feign client and client's applicatin.properties file solves my problem.